# Swapping 2 or more blocks in angular 4

Tags: angular

I need to swap more than two div's in angular 4 [image]

I'm using angular 2 drag gable but it not working

Comment: Why people down vote my question i can't understand

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: i didn't get any idea and der is no single line of code for this one.I want some refernce

Answer (score 0):

I think ngx-bootstrap sortable module can help you out to solve your problem.

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/sortable